# HTML not loading local images in any of my browsers in my system

Tags: filesystems, webserver, images, html

Problem

In my main desktop system running Arch linux, when I create an HTML file with a tag and an image like so:

```html
<img src="imagepath" alt="sometext">
```

the image does not appear in any browsers. The image path is properly set, having already tried relative, absoulte and file:// paths and none of them work.

The strangest thing

The thing that bothers me is that if I take the same steps in my laptop running Linux mint 20, everything works just fine, so the issue here is not just me being dumb.

I also installed a Debian VM to test with, and also had no issue whatsoever.

Things that I tried:

- Disabling extensions as NoScript
- Trying all the different combinations of image paths.
- Trying out different web browsers (both firefox like and chromium like).
- Using Visual Studio Code's Five Live server to test with a server.
- Hosting both files with NGINX.
- Playing with image's permissions

Has somebody heard anything like this before?

If somebody was able to help, it would mean a lot.

my complete code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head><!--{{{-->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <title>Vieml</title>
    </head><!-- }}} -->

    <body>
        <h1>My first webpage</h1>
        <p>this is sample text</p>

        <img scr="BR.jpg" alt="image"/>

    </body>

</html>
```

And the directory structure is:

```bash
~/code/website ❯ tree
.
├── BR.jpg
├── index.html
└── test.html
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: not knowing Arch's security features well enough to make a qualified statement, but: this sounds either like your browsers are configured to not ever load local images, or something blocks the browser processes accessing the path where said image lies; for example, not allowing browser to access resources in your home directory (outside ~/.cache, ~/.config/browsername, or ~/.browsername) does sound like a pretty good idea to protect users from all kinds of data exfiltration tricks that you could do with HTML files.

Comment: but: this is all speculation. You will have to fill us in on the actual file location, and the actual image location. I don't really thing "imagepath" will cut it here. Also: can you directly open the image in your browser?

Comment: And show the url of the html page.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My file is in a subdirectory of my home folder yes, in a folder called $HOME/code/web/, where both the html file and the image are located. And yes, I am able to open the image directly on my browser.

Comment: that's really mystifying! Care to share the verbatim source code, at least of the `<img>` tag, plus maybe the content of `<head></head>`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry for making you wait, I just uploaded my entire code up so you can see everything properly, but I must say that I have no clue to whatever is going on.

Comment: Your "complete code" uses an `img` node with a `scr` attribute. This is probably a typo? Should be `src`.

Comment: I'm on Arch as well, and do not have this problem; it's definitely not default Arch behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got me a while to notice it, but the thing is that I have not finished my VIM setup in Arch, but I do have a bit nicer on debian.
One of the things I've got in my Debian machine which I do not have in my newer arch machine is a file linter.

The problem was as @Kusalananda commented, that I misspelled `src` as `scr`, and when I moved my file into Debian, it linted it and fixed it automatically for me, causing me a lot of confusion as of why it worked in Debian and not in Arch.

Anyway, thanks to all for having replied to my silly post.

Have nice days!